# ConcurrentHashMap does not work as expected

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I am counting votes for electronic election and I have only one party in my initial version. There will be different threads per voter and the threads will update the votes count of a given party.

I decided to use ConcurrentHashMap, but the results are not what I expected...

```
Map<String, Integer> voting = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  new Thread(() -> {
    voting.put("GERB", voting.getOrDefault("GERB", 0) + 1);
  }).start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  voting.put("GERB", voting.getOrDefault("GERB", 0) + 1);
}

Thread.sleep(5000); // Waits for the threads to finish

for (String s : voting.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(s + ": " + voting.get(s));
}
```

The result is different every time - it ranges from 114 to 116.

Isn't ConcurrentHashMap supposed to be synchronised?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there's a compound action here. You get the map value given a key, increment it by one, and place it back in the map against the same key. You have to guarantee that all these statements execute atomically. But the given implementation does not impose that prerequisite. Hence you end up with a safety failure.

To fix this, you can use the atomic `merge` operation defined in `ConcurrentHashMap`. The entire method invocation is performed atomically. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<String, Integer> voting = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    new Thread(() -> {
        voting.merge("GERB", 1, Integer::sum);
    }).start();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    voting.merge("GERB", 1, Integer::sum);

Thread.sleep(5000); // Waits for the threads to finish

for (String s : voting.keySet())
    System.out.println(s + ": " + voting.get(s));
```

Running this program produces the following output:

> GERB: 116

Answer (score 3):

Assume there are two or more threads performs
 `voting.put("GERB", voting.getOrDefault("GERB", 0) + 1);`

what happens?
Lets say value on key "GERB" now equals 10

1. Thread #1 gets value `voting.getOrDefault("GERB", 0)`. It is 10
2. Thread #2 gets value `voting.getOrDefault("GERB", 0)`. It is 10
3. Thread #1 adds 1, now it is 11
4. Thread #2 adds 1, now it is 11
5. Thread #1 writes values 11 back to `voting`
6. Thread #2 writes values 11 back to `voting`

Now, although 2 threads completes, the value increased only by 1 because of concurency.

So, yes, methods of `ConcurrentHashMap` are synchronized. That means, when one thread executes e.g. `put`, another thread waits. But they do not synchronize threads outside anyhow.

If you perform several calls you have to synchronize them on your own. E.g.:

```
final Map<String, Integer> voting = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  new Thread(() -> {
    synchronized (voting) { // synchronize the whole operation over the same object
       voting.put("GERB", voting.getOrDefault("GERB", 0) + 1);
    }
  }).start();
}
```

**UPD**
As it noted in the comments, keep in mind that synchronization over `voting` object does not guarantee synchronization with ConcurentHahMap's methods itself. You have to perform that synchronization for every call to `voting` methods if those calls can be performed concurrently. In fact, you can use any other object to synchronize (it's not required to be `voting`): it only needs to be the same for all the threads.

But, as it noted by @Holger, this defeats the very purpose of the `ConcurentHashMap`.
To utilize the atomic mechanics of `ConcurentHashMap` without locking the threads you can use method [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#replace-K-V-V-) to retry the operation if the value was altered by another thread:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  new Thread(() -> {
    Integer oldValue, newValue;
    do {
       oldValue = voting.getOrDefault("GERB", 0);
       newValue = oldValue + 1; // do some actions over the value
    } while (!voting.replace("GERB", oldValue, newValue)); // repeat if the value was changed
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: Methods of `ConcurrentHashMap` are *not* synchronized. They are atomic in respect to each other, but that’s a different mechanism. So when you use `synchronized(voting)`, you are protecting against other threads also using `synchronized (voting)`, but not against concurrent modifications like `put` calls without that synchronization. You’d need to wrap every access in such a synchronized block to make it work, which is defeating the entire purpose of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @Holger that's true. I updated the answer to clarify this.

Comment: So, ConcurrentHashMap just makes sure that if one thread calls 'put' another cannot, but does not lock other methods like 'get'?

Comment: @Vallerious it does not lock methods at whole, but just guarantee consistent result. I.e. concurrent performing of `put` and `get` methods in different threads will not damage not the map nor value. I.e. `get` will return either the previous value or the new one

Answer (score 3):

You can divide this line `voting.put("GERB", voting.getOrDefault("GERB", 0) + 1);` into three steps:

```
int temp=voting.getOrDefault("GERB",0); //1
temp++;                                 //2
voting.put("GERB",temp);                //3
```

Now between line1 and line3, Other thread can change the value associated with "GERB" because the method has return, there is nothing can stop other thread from changing it. So when you call `voting.put("GERB",temp)`,you override their value which makes their update lost.